# OracleCachedRowSet or RowSet

Tags: java, jdbc

What is the difference (advantages / disadvantages of both of them) between OracleCachedRowSet and RowSet in Java?

Comment: Please define "better" in your case. What are you after? Given the fact that `OracleCachedRowSet` seems to be vendor specific I'd rather use `RowSet` unless vendor specific functionality is really needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OracleCachedRowSet` is the Oracle JDBC driver's implementation of the `RowSet` and `CachedRowSet` interfaces. You should stick to using `RowSet` or `CachedRowSet` only, unless you have a very compelling reason to use the Oracle-specific class, such as wanting to use proprietary methods that are present on `OracleCachedRowSet` but not on `RowSet` or `CachedRowSet`.

Note that your program will be using `OracleCachedRowSet` at runtime, regardless of whether your source code refers to `OracleCachedRowSet` or `RowSet`.